# Read first N mb of a file

Tags: python

I am looking to get the first N mb of a file. Here is a basic implementation:

```
def get_first_n_mb(self, file=None, n=5):
    """
    Will return the first 5 (or N) MB of the passed file
    """
    file = file or self.file

    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        file_data = self.file_first_n_mb = fp.read(1e6 * n)

    return file_data
```

However, the user may pass a large number, such as n = 1000, in which case we would want to chunk the read. What would be a good 'size' to do the chunk, or would the above approach still work? How could it be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` is permitted to return less than the amount you asked for. You should call it in a loop until you reach the amount requested or EOF. You need to keep reducing the amount you need to read by the size of the last read.

```
def get_first_n_mb(self, file=None, n=5):
    file = file or self.file
    amt = 1e6 * n
    file_data = ''
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        while amt > 0:
            try:
                block = fp.read(amt)
                file_data += block
                amt -= len(block)
            except EOFError:
                break
    return file_data
```

For ordinary files `read()` will normally return as much as you request, as long as the file is that long. But other types of streams will often return less (e.g. reading from a terminal will usually just return one line).